# What command can mount an SSH share and launch a file?

Tags: ssh, scripts, share, remote, command-line

I have a file on another Ubuntu machine. I want to access it from my machine on my LAN. I don't want to go into Nautilus to mount the share first and then browse to the file. I want a command that will connect via SSH automatically (by mounting its share if not already or however) and open that file on my machine in the associated program (assume I do have that program install on my machine).

Any simple way to do this? I will be putting this command into a launcher so I can just double-click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have sshfs set up ;)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Mount your sshfs
sshfs your_server:/sshfs_share /media/sshfs_share

#Use zenity to ask what file to open
file=$(zenity --entry --text "What file?")

# Or use a zenity file chooser
file=$(zenity --file-selection --title="Select a File)

# Open a file
gedit $file
```

For options with zenity, see [zenity by example](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/259/a-complete-zenity-dialog-examples-1/) or man zenity

You can certainly elaborate on the script, adding error checking, check the existence of the file , etc, but that will get a good start.

Comment: See also [sshfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS). However, I think the instructions there on creating the "fuse" group and adding the user to it are no longer current, as I believe the "fuse" group is now included by default in Ubuntu, and regular users are members by default.

Comment: The script you have made looks very good, thanks. Is there a way to access the remote file via SSH without mounting the share? Lets assume the file is a text file, and I want to open it with gedit on my local machine. Or alternatively, if it must mount the share, can it avoid asking me for the remote server's password?

Comment: You can edit files remotely with vim, gvim or cream for a graphical interface. If you do not want to enter a password, use a ssh key and ssh agent. `vim scp://user@server//path/to/document` vim will open, there will be a short pause while it makes the connection, and then you will be asked to enter your password. See also http://linuxblog.pansapiens.com/2008/07/13/edit-remote-files-over-ssh-scp-using-gvim/ and http://thecodecentral.com/2010/04/02/use-gedit-as-remote-file-editor-via-ftp-and-ssh-ubuntu If you are connecting from windows, you can do this with winscp